# VBA issue with SaveAs after moving to Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365, readonly

I'm experiencing problems with my macro that was written under Excel 2010 after moving to Office 365.
In short - I've got a macro stored in a central file stored in a sharedrive that opens several files from different SharePoint folders, pastes some data in each and saves. To do that I use:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open (filename:=path, UpdateLinks:=0)
[some code]
WB.SaveAs Filename=:path
```

This was perfectly fine under excel 2010, now I get

> RunTime Error 1004.

Also, when I stop the macro completely after it crashes on the SaveAs method, and try to do the saving manually - entire excel crashes immediately and restarts..
I tried googling differences between the excel generations in that context but I found nothing. I also tried adding more attributes - both to file opening and saving methods, like `readonly:=false, ignorereadonlyrecommendation:=true, file format:=xlworbookdefault` etc, no effect.
I also noticed, that when macro crashes, the file that was supposed to be saved and closed is in `ReadOnly` despite including `readonly:=false` in the `Workbooks.open` method - as if this was completely ignored..

Any help is appreciated, this tool is key to my daily work and so far upgrading to new excel made everything worse:[

Comment: If you're saving the file you opened to the same location wouldn't `WB.Save` work?

Comment: There is a piece of code prior to file opening that let's me choose if I want to open the file already stored on the Sharepoint, or use a template (all Sharepoint files use the same layout but different data, if I need to change the layout I use "open template and save as" instead of replacing multiple files manually

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer - apparently it was related to opening files from server (the Sharepoint piece) and due to that a new line of code is necessary which is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile
```

I never used that before while on Excel 2010, didn't even know it existed up until now